# SwiftUI - Empty bottom bar after tapping NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` with a `toolbar` that contains a `ToolBarItem` with a `.bottomBar` placement and a search field. This `NavigationView` contains a `ScrollView` with content that exceeds the screen's vertical size, which means that the bottom bar has a background, as seen below:

[image: Root View Screenshot]

When the user taps the "Root View" text element they navigate to a new view, in this case, just another text displaying "Detail View". The problem, however, is that the bottom toolbar's background remains in the screen instead of vanishing as expected. See the screenshot below:

[image]

This behavior is not seen if I remove the search bar or shrink the `ScrollView`'s height to fit the vertical dimension of the device. I tried googling this issue to see if it was a known bug with a workaround but maybe I'm not searching the right keywords. How can I fix this issue?

Please see the bare minimum to replicate the issue below:

```
struct BugView: View {
    @State var searchPattern: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail View")) {
                        Text("Root View").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Root View Bottom").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 1000)
            }
                .searchable(text: self.$searchPattern, prompt: "Search Here")
                .toolbar(content: {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                        Text("Toolbar text")
                    }
                })
           }
   }
}
```

Setup:

- XCode Version: 13.4.1
- Simulator: iPhone 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .toolbar(.hidden, for: .bottomBar) for the destination view as shown in the code below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                Text("Destination View")
            } label: {
                // hiding the toolbar for the destination view 
                Text("Root View").toolbar(.hidden, for: .bottomBar)
            }

        }.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Text("Toolbar Text")
                    .background {
                        Color.gray
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @azamsharp. I tried implementing your suggestion but there's no implementation of `toolbar` that works with the signature you used (`.toolbar(.hidden, for: .bottomBar)`). What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm. I am using Xcode 14 and iOS 16.

Comment: right, it looks like this is new to iOS 16. Any ideas on how to fix it for <16?

Comment: Not sure about < 16. You may need to create a custom bottom bar for the view that you want.